# Get one record from left join if count is 1 else null

Tags: left-join, impala

I have a table Employee with primary key as Employee_id and other table for email address which has multiple email address for one employee. I need to get all employees from Table 1 with logic that if one email address exists then it is pulled from Table "Email" , if more than one then null.
Table 1 data

[image]

[image]

I tried to write it as below query and it is not working. Can anyone please help. ALl your inputs are greatly appreciated.

SELECT employee_id,

CASE WHEN count(adr.email_addr) =1 and count(dupes.email_addr)=1 and adr.email_addr=dupes.email_addr

then adr.email_addr

else null END email_address

FROM Employee Emp

LEFT OUTER JOIN

(SELECT employee_id, email_addr, count(*) qty

FROM Emailadress

HAVING count(*) > 1)

dupes 
ON EMP.employee_id = dupes.employee_id

group by emp.employee_id, adr.email_addr

I am using impala interface to execute.

Thanks,

Manju

Comment: Please read & act on google hits re formatting code in SO posts, eg read the help above the edit box. Also [using text, not images/links, for text, including tables](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Also [mcve].

Comment: What if there are no emails for an id?